# Линейнонезависимая система векторов

Tags: математика, линейная-алгебра

Есть такой пример:

```
Пусть М - линейное пространство многочленов степени, меньшей либо равной n. 
Системе векторов е = {1, x, x^2...x^n} является линейно независимой для любого x.
```

Я не понимаю почему это так, ведь можно подобрать такие коэффициенты, что в итоге при суммировании получится нулевой вектор, а константы не все нулевые.
Вот, например:

```
Есть система единичных векторов {{1},{2},{4}}
Очевидно, что если взять c1 за 0, с2 за -2, с3 за 1, то получится нулевой вектор и, 
как следствие, линейнозависимая система.
```

Comment: Так подберите, если можно. Вы не сможете уничтожить степени, не зануляя все коэффициенты.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, так я привел пример, там не все коэффициенты нулевые, не понимаю в чем он неверный

Comment: И где там многочлены? У вас там три единичных вектора, любая система из двух и более единичных векторов будет линейно зависима.

Comment: `{1}`, `{2}`, `{4}` не являются элементами M. Элементами пространства являются многчлены. Покажите пример линейной комбинации `1`, `x` и `x^2`, которая будет равна нулю

Comment: @RomanKonoval, по аналогии с1 = 0, с2 = -х, с3 = 1, видимо я неправильно понимаю, что такое линейное пространство многочленов

Comment: Коэффициенты берутся только из поля вещественных чисел.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, тогда, если, например коэффициенты c1 = 0, c2 = -2, c3 = 1, то для x = 2 это не сработает, разве не так?

Comment: В пространстве многочленов нулевым вектором является нулевой многочлен. То есть он равен тождественно нулю при любых X.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, понял, спасибо!